# Virtual cam with v4l2loopback

Tags: c++, linux, v4l2

I try to develop my own virtual webcam. Therefore I play with v4l2loopback and try to understand this tutorial: https://arcoresearchgroup.wordpress.com/2020/06/02/virtual-camera-for-opencv-using-v4l2loopback/

I have encountered some problems, when I use the exact same program like in this tutorial. The program will be compiled and get started, but when I try to watch my virtual device with ffplay or vlc I just get only one frame and a core dumped error. I don't know why this happens, maybe one of you can help me.

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/videodev2.h>

#ifndef VID_WIDTH
#define VID_WIDTH 640
#endif

#ifndef VID_HEIGHT
#define VID_HEIGHT 480
#endif

#define VIDEO_IN  "/dev/video0"
#define VIDEO_OUT "/dev/video6"

int
main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    // open and configure input camera (/dev/video0)
    cv::VideoCapture cam(VIDEO_IN);
    if (not cam.isOpened()) {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: could not open camera!\n";
        return -1;
    }
    cam.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 480);
    cam.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 640);

    // open output device
    int output = open(VIDEO_OUT, O_RDWR);
    if(output < 0) {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: could not open output device!\n" << strerror(errno);
        return -2;
    }

    // configure params for output device
    struct v4l2_format vid_format;
    memset(&vid_format, 0, sizeof(vid_format));
    vid_format.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_OUTPUT;

    if (ioctl(output, VIDIOC_G_FMT, &vid_format) < 0) {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: unable to get video format!\n" << strerror(errno);
        return -1;
    }

    size_t framesize = VID_WIDTH * VID_HEIGHT * 3;
    vid_format.fmt.pix.width = cam.get(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
    vid_format.fmt.pix.height = cam.get(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);

    // NOTE: change this according to below filters...
    // Chose one from the supported formats on Chrome:
    // - V4L2_PIX_FMT_YUV420,
    // - V4L2_PIX_FMT_Y16,
    // - V4L2_PIX_FMT_Z16,
    // - V4L2_PIX_FMT_INVZ,
    // - V4L2_PIX_FMT_YUYV,
    // - V4L2_PIX_FMT_RGB24,
    // - V4L2_PIX_FMT_MJPEG,
    // - V4L2_PIX_FMT_JPEG
    vid_format.fmt.pix.pixelformat = V4L2_PIX_FMT_RGB24;

    vid_format.fmt.pix.sizeimage = framesize;
    vid_format.fmt.pix.field = V4L2_FIELD_NONE;

    if (ioctl(output, VIDIOC_S_FMT, &vid_format) < 0) {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: unable to set video format!\n" << strerror(errno);
        return -1;
    }

    // create GUI window
    const char* gui = "gui";
    cv::namedWindow(gui);
    cv::setWindowTitle(gui, "OpenCV test");

    // loop over these actions:
    while (true) {

        // grab frame
        cv::Mat frame;
        if (not cam.grab()) {
            std::cerr << "ERROR: could not read from camera!\n";
            break;
        }
        //cam.retrieve(frame);
    cam >> frame;
        // apply simple filter (NOTE: result should be as defined PIXEL FORMAT)
        // convert twice because we need RGB24
        cv::Mat result;
        cv::cvtColor(frame, result, cv::COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
        cv::cvtColor(result, result, cv::COLOR_GRAY2RGB);

        // show frame
        cv::imshow("gui", result);

        // write frame to output device
        size_t written = write(output, result.data, framesize);
        if (written < 0) {
            std::cerr << "ERROR: could not write to output device!\n";
            close(output);
            break;
        }

        // wait for user to finish program pressing ESC
        if (cv::waitKey(10) == 27)
            break;
    }

    std::cout << "\n\nFinish, bye!\n";
}
```

The issue trace:

```
ffplay /dev/video6
ffplay version 4.2.7-0ubuntu0.1 Copyright (c) 2003-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-nvenc --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Input #0, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video6':
  Duration: N/A, start: 104476.472687, bitrate: 221184 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (RGB[24] / 0x18424752), rgb24, 640x480, 221184 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
Speicherzugriffsfehler (Speicherabzug geschrieben)B sq=    0B f=0/0
```

In addition, I changed pixel format and get with the parameter MJPEG this issue, when I try the command ffplay /dev/video6:

```
ffplay /dev/video6
ffplay version 4.2.7-0ubuntu0.1 Copyright (c) 2003-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-nvenc --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
[mjpeg @ 0x7f159c002280] No JPEG data found in image=    0B f=0/0   
[mjpeg @ 0x7f159c002280] bits 246 is invalid
[mjpeg @ 0x7f159c002280] bits 247 is invalid  0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[mjpeg @ 0x7f159c002280] No JPEG data found in image=    0B f=0/0   
[mjpeg @ 0x7f159c002280] No JPEG data found in image=    0B f=0/0   
[mjpeg @ 0x7f159c002280] No JPEG data found in image=    0B f=0/0   
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x7f159c000bc0] decoding for stream 0 failed
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x7f159c000bc0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: mjpeg (JPEG LS), none(bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 640x480, lossless): unspecified pixel format
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video6':B sq=    0B f=0/0   
  Duration: N/A, start: 106356.321454, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (JPEG LS), none(bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 640x480, lossless, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
[mjpeg @ 0x7f159c00a500] invalid id 238
[mjpeg @ 0x7f159c00a500] invalid id 242
[mjpeg @ 0x7f159c00a500] invalid id 238
[mjpeg @ 0x7f159c00a500] invalid id 242
[mjpeg @ 0x7f159c00a500] invalid id 238
[mjpeg @ 0x7f159c00a500] invalid id 242
[mjpeg @ 0x7f159c00a500] invalid id 247vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[mjpeg @ 0x7f159c00a500] bits 248 is invalid  0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[mjpeg @ 0x7f159c00a500] bits 248 is invalid  0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[mjpeg @ 0x7f159c00a500] invalid id 244vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[mjpeg @ 0x7f159c00a500] bits 245 is invalid  0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[mjpeg @ 0x7f159c00a500] invalid id 244vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[mjpeg @ 0x7f159c00a500] invalid id 245vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[mjpeg @ 0x7f159c00a500] invalid id 215vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[mjpeg @ 0x7f159c00a500] invalid id 244vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[mjpeg @ 0x7f159c00a500] invalid id 244vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[mjpeg @ 0x7f159c00a500] invalid id 247vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[mjpeg @ 0x7f159c00a500] invalid id 240vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[mjpeg @ 0x7f159c00a500] bits 241 is invalid  0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[mjpeg @ 0x7f159c00a500] invalid id 247vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[mjpeg @ 0x7f159c00a500] No JPEG data found in image=    0B f=0/0   
[mjpeg @ 0x7f159c00a500] No JPEG data found in image=    0B f=0/0   
[mjpeg @ 0x7f159c00a500] invalid id 250vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0
```

In addition:
I tried several pixel formats and something happened. Pixel format "RGB24" worked, but just for one time. When I shutdown the program and restarted it, the same issue popped up. Maybe this detail helps you to help me.
best regards

**Edit**

I need to update this post. The program works fine! When I push out the image over /dev/video6 with the pixel format RGB24, it works fine when I use another programm and fetch the stream with opencv. When I use vlc, ffmpeg or other programs, it did not work. When I try it in pixel format V4L2_PIX_FMT_GREY ffmpeg works very fine but vlc didn't work again. Have someone an idea where I should look now or has a hint for me what I can do now?

Best regards

Comment: Run your code under a debugger.  It'll provide you with a lot of useful info.

Comment: Please include the backtrace for the crash along with your code, a [mre].